# Calling a function asynchronously?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

I have an expensive function, createNewWindow().  I want to show a progress indicator when the method gets called, and then hide that indicator when the function finishes. Everything I've tried though, I don't see the progress indicator until the method has finshed, so I'm trying to call that method asychronously (and failing).

I tried this:

```
$( "#submit" ).click( function () {
    $("#progress").show();
    $.Deferred(createNewWindow());
} );
```

And the last line of createNewWindow was $("#progress").show().  Didn't work. Before that I tried:

```
$( "#submit" ).click( function () {
    $("#progress").show();
    setTimeout(createNewWindow(), 0);
} );
```

Same effect.

What's the right way to do this?

I saw a few other SO posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9516900/how-can-i-create-an-asynchronous-function-on-javascript) that describe using setInterval or setTimeout, but I was unable to get them to work like I was expecting.

Comment: Calling a synchronous function in an asynchronous way does'nt make it so. It will still block the browser, and your best bet is an image of something spinning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common mistake. The problem is right here:

```
setTimeout(createNewWindow(), 0);
```

This will call `createNewWindow` immediately and pass the result (probably void) to `setTimeout`. That's not what you want, you want to pass the *function* `createNewWindow` to `setTimeout` for it to call it at a later time:

```
setTimeout(createNewWindow, 0);
```

Note the missing parentheses. You're passing the value of `createNewWindow` (which is a function) to `setTimeout`, instead of calling it and passing its return value.

This should make the progress bar show up right away. However, if `createNewWindow` is a really expensive function eating lots of resources, it *will* still slow down your web page since all your JavaScript code is run in the same thread. In that case, you might want to consider [using a `Worker`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Using_web_workers).

Comment: This is a great catch, thanks!  Unfortunately it still doesn't get that progress to show up properly... probably because it is as you mention on the same thread.  However, I only see examples of workers that take a URL to a js file?   Is there a way to create a new Worker with a function?  Maybe just as easy as `new Worker(createNewWindow)`?