# window.print is blocking the javascript execution in the source window

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

In my web app i want to integrate a print functionality. When the user clicks the print button, a new window is opening and the print dialog appears. With this code i want to achieve this:

```
    var win = window.open(url, '_blank');
    win.print();
```

It is working, but the problem is that in chrome the source window stops the javascript execution while the print dialog is open. How is it possible to prevent this?

Comment: Can you share the complete code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I create an Asynchronous function on Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9516900/how-can-i-create-an-asynchronous-function-on-javascript)

Comment: Here is an example code: http://jsfiddle.net/Zicane/7ntsb7hh/10/

Comment: @Zicane how to you fixed this problem?

Comment: @Andy, did anyone of you found a solution to this?

Comment: Strangely, in my app the click callbacks do get executed, but setInterval callbacks don't, here's a codepen illustrating this: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wRMGrb I would actually expect the page to stop execution completely, since JS is single threaded, and I'm just really curious what is actually happening there.