# Workers doesn't work in HTML page embedded in WPF project

Tags: javascript, html, wpf, multithreading

When executing scripts in an HTML page, the page becomes unresponsive until the script is finished.
Thus I want to use workers.
I have a problem:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="startWorker()">Start Worker</button> 
<button onclick="stopWorker()">Stop Worker</button>
<br><br>

<script>
    var w;

    function startWorker()
    {
        if (typeof (Worker) !== "undefined")
        {
            if (typeof (w) == "undefined")
            {
               // Do something
            }
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Browser does not support Web Workers.");
        }
    }

    function stopWorker()
    {
        w.terminate();
        w = undefined;
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I get the "Browser does not support Web Workers." message.

Is there other way to use multithreading so the page becomes responsive before the script is finished?

Thanks a lot,
Orian.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9516900/how-can-i-create-an-asynchronous-function-on-javascript

Comment: You might also be interested in frp libraries like kefir: http://pozadi.github.io/kefir/

Comment: But if you want *true* multithreading, I'm afraid the only solution is Web workers.

Comment: @didierc even if you defer the execution via `setTimeout`, this still does not prevent the function from blocking once its executed. You could break the function into multiple `setTimeout`s but that can sometimes be impractical.

Comment: @didierc, as levi said - setTimeoutstill does not prevent the function from blocking once its executed.
thanks anyway :)

Comment: That was a knee jerk reaction to the more general question: "how to do multithreading in js?". As I said later on, for **true** multithreading I don't think there's an alternative to `Worker`s. This being said, if you reformulate your question as: how do I **change** my code so that it becomes responsive while seemingly handling several tasks, the other question and its answers still applies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the scripts make your page unresponsive, they're poorly programmed. Look into asynchronous programming - after all, JS has worked for many years without workers.

That said, if you really need web workers, you essentially have some choices:

- Start using another embedded browser, these include: CefSharp, Awesomium. These should support web workers.
- Try and see if this problem is still happening with the latest `WebBrowser`, for example, IE11: http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2011/May/21/Web-Browser-Control-Specifying-the-IE-Version
- You can always offload the work into C# side, and push results through interop to Javascript.

Comment: To be fair, the tasks used for JS now are very different from those in the past (eg: pixel-level processing).

Comment: offload the work into C# side sound good to me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The C# solution is not for browser without workers, it's for IE. Is IE the only browser not having support for workers?

Comment: I have IE11 and it does support workers, but in my WPF project it doesn't.

Comment: @OrianZinger; that's because WPF uses IE7 by default and IE7 does not support web workers. If you force WPF to use IE11(see link in my answer), it will work - I've tested.

Comment: I can't use IE11 in my WPF, so I forced it to use IE10 and still i get the same result. IE10 should support web workers. When I forced it to use IE11 it worked, but my Google Earth Plugin didn't like it. I had to download the plugin again and even though - it didn't work.