# Can i call in javascript a javascript function that runs in background or asynchronously making browser not freeze?

Tags: javascript, browser, background, freeze

```
function test() {
    some_code;
}

function do_many_test() {
    var i;
    for(i=0;i<100;i++){
        test();
    }
    some_code;
    some_code;
    some_code;
}
```

The function do_many_test() makes browser stuck for about ten seconds: is there a way to call it making it running in background while the execution flow continues to next code?

Comment: something called ajax maybe..  also look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9516900/how-can-i-create-an-asynchronous-function-on-javascript

Answer (score 0):

If you are using modern browser. you can use
webworker
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers