# setInterval() - but run it only once

Tags: javascript, html

If I call the update function several times I get multiple instances of this interval running. How can I be sure that this only gets triggered once per idVar?

For example if I run this twice in a row with the same idVar I get two updates per second, where it should only be one.

If the idVar is different it should run multiple times. idVar is used in Update().

```
intervals[idVar] = setInterval(function() {
    update();                            
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Just use a condition, `if ( ! idVar in intervals ) ...`

Comment: Use `setTmeout()` instead of `setInterval()`.

Comment: @ScottMarcus yeah, I wonder why interval instead of timeout...

Comment: This question might help you choose another option as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9516900/how-can-i-create-an-asynchronous-function-in-javascript

Comment: `setTimeout` does only get called once, BUT if called _**multiple**_ times and set to the _**same**_ object property, **multiple** instances will still be created.  **The original question asks how to avoid multiple instances of intervals/timeouts being instantiated**.  I've made a submission to edit the question to clarify this as well as adding my answer below

Comment: Can you post your  **update()** function, please?

Comment: all of these comments miss the point.. I'm guessing the easiest way is to have an outside variable that acts as a semaphore - and a try { } finally { } sort of scenario ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want a new instance of the interval running for each unique idVar, you just need to check to see if you already have an instance of the interval running for the current idVar:

```
if (!intervals[idVar]) {
    intervals[idVar] = setInterval(function() {
        update();                            
    }, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
intervals[idVar] = setTimeout(function() {
    update();                            
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to use setInterval and dont want to use setTimeout , you can clear it when you enter function

For example

```
var interval

interval = setInterval(function(){
   clearInterval(interval)
  //Your code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**`setInterval`** returns a **timeoutID** that is used to identify it.

To stop a `setInterval` you pass it's timoueID to `clearInterval`.

---

> #### Explanation of why you get two intervals running
>
> When you do this:
>
> ```
> intervals[idVar] = setInterval(function() { update(); }, 1000);
> intervals[idVar] = setInterval(function() { update(); }, 1000);
> ```
>
> What you are doing is:
>
> - call your *first* `setInterval` and setting `intervals[idVar]` to this first `setInterval's` **timeoutID**
> - call your second `setInterval` and **overwrite** the value stored in `intervals[idVar]` with the timeoutID of your ***newly*** called
>     `setInterval`
>
> **Result**: Two seperate intervals, with `intervals[idVar]` storing the timeoutID of the second one called

---

#### setTimeout

setTimeout is like setInterval and actually uses the same pool of timeout IDs, but it is only invoked once after the specified delay.

---

> ## Setting one interval (setTimeout or setInterval) per idVar
>
> ```
> var idVar = setInterval(function() { 
>                           update(); 
>                         }, 1000);  // sets idVar to the timeoutID and starts the interval
> }
> intervals[idVar] = idVar;  // assigns a property 'idVar' on `intervals`
>                            // and sets the timeoutID as its value
>                            // allows you to call clearInterval(intervals[idVar]);
> ```
>
> However, without knowing exactly what your `update()` method is doing it is difficult to tell what the best solution would be here...