# html button execute jquery and javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello so im trying to make a button that does two thing at the same time

```js
function clickimageone(l){
 alert("test");
 question1button1 = true;
}
```

```css
}
.border1{
 border: 1px solid red;
}
.border2{
 border: 1px solid red;
}
.border3{
 border: 1px solid red;
}
.border4{
 border: 1px solid red;
}
.image{
 float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="image"><img src="img/500.png" onclick="clickimageone()" class="border1" style="height: 500px; max-height: 150px; max-width: 300px; top: 50px; left: 50px"></div>
<div class="image"><img src="img/1000.png" onclick="clickimagetwo(this)" class="border2" style="height: 500px; max-height: 150px; max-width: 300px; top: 50px; left: 100px"></div>
<div class="image"><img src="img/1500.png" onclick="clickimagethree(this)" class="border3" style="height: 500px; max-height: 150px; max-width: 300px; top: 50px; left: 150px"></div>
<div class="image"><img src="img/2000.png" onclick="clickimagefour(this)" class="border4" style="height: 500px; max-height: 150px; max-width: 300px; top: 50px; left: 200px"></div>



<script>
  $('.border1').click(function(e){    
    $('.image, .border1, .border2, .border3, .border4').fadeOut('slow', function(){
        $('.image, .border2').fadeIn('slow');
    });
});


</script>
```

So basically when people press on the image it will execute jquery to fade in and out some stuff and at the same time to execute a java function to alert users.     So my question is can i make it so when the user click on the image it will fade out the picture and fade in a new picture and also alert the user at the same time.

Comment: This discussion may be of use: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9516900/how-can-i-create-an-asynchronous-function-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

Used `addClass()` and `.removeClass()` instead of `.fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()`. Targeted the `img` container instead of the `img` itself.

BTW, if you use jQuery, you'll never have the need to use an attribute event handler (i.e. `onclick`).

**Details commented in demo**

### Demo

```js
// Counter
var idx = 0;
// Any <li> clicked...
$('li').on('click', function() {
  // Increment counter
  idx++;
  // Find the next <li>
  var next = $(this).next('li');
  // Remove the .on class on all img
  $('li').removeClass('on');
  // Add .on class to next <li>
  next.addClass('on');
  /* As you can see, the function runs both each time.
  || If you are looking for something that's simultaneous, 
  || then try another language because JavaScript is one thread.
  */ // The string is a template literal each click changes the count.
  alert(`Hey don't use alert it's annoying!Test with console.log() instead. This image ${idx}`);
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none
}

li img {
  display: none;
}

.on img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class='on'><img src='http://placehold.it/150x150/000/fff?text=1'></li>
  <li><img src='http://placehold.it/150x150/0ff/000?text=2'></li>
  <li><img src='http://placehold.it/150x150/83d800/000?text=3'></li>
  <li><img src='http://placehold.it/150x150/f7a/000?text=4'></li>
  <li><img src='http://placehold.it/150x150/fc0/000?text=5'></li>
  <li><img src='http://placehold.it/150x150/f00/fff?text=6'></li>
</ul>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Please try this...it works for me...I had included the jquery     

<style>
    }
    .border1{
        border: 1px solid red;
    }
    .border2{
        border: 1px solid red;
    }
    .border3{
        border: 1px solid red;
    }
    .border4{
        border: 1px solid red;
    }
    .image{
        float: left;
    }
    </style>
    <div class="image"><img src="img/500.png" onclick="clickimageone()" class="border1" style="height: 500px; max-height: 150px; max-width: 300px; top: 50px; left: 50px"></div>
    <div class="image"><img src="img/1000.png" onclick="clickimagetwo(this)" class="border2" style="height: 500px; max-height: 150px; max-width: 300px; top: 50px; left: 100px"></div>
    <div class="image"><img src="img/1500.png" onclick="clickimagethree(this)" class="border3" style="height: 500px; max-height: 150px; max-width: 300px; top: 50px; left: 150px"></div>
    <div class="image"><img src="img/2000.png" onclick="clickimagefour(this)" class="border4" style="height: 500px; max-height: 150px; max-width: 300px; top: 50px; left: 200px"></div>


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
            $('.border1').click(function(e){    
        $('.image, .border1, .border2, .border3, .border4').fadeOut('slow', function(){
            $('.image, .border2').fadeIn('slow');
        });
    });
```

Comment: i tried but then the jquery wasn't being executed so i just put it in the html body

Comment: The jquery is not working because the jquery is not included

Comment: I did include it

Answer (score 0):

please include jquery js in your html file

```js
function clickimageone(l){
 
}
$('.img_cls').click(function(e){  
     alert("test");
   question1button1 = true;
       $('.img_cls').fadeOut('slow', function(){
          $('.image, .border2').fadeIn('slow');
        });
});
```

```css
}
.border1{
 border: 1px solid red;
}
.border2{
 border: 1px solid red;
}
.border3{
 border: 1px solid red;
}
.border4{
 border: 1px solid red;
}
.image{
 float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="image"><img src="https://png.icons8.com/plus/win8/26"  class="border1 img_cls" style="height: 500px; max-height: 150px; max-width: 300px; top: 50px; left: 50px"></div>
<div class="image "><img src="https://png.icons8.com/minus/ios7/100"  class="border2 img_cls" style="height: 500px; max-height: 150px; max-width: 300px; top: 50px; left: 100px"></div>
<div class="image img_cls"><img src="https://png.icons8.com/plus/win8/26"  class="border3 img_cls" style="height: 500px; max-height: 150px; max-width: 300px; top: 50px; left: 150px"></div>
<div class="image"><img src="https://png.icons8.com/minus/ios7/100"  class="border4 img_cls" style="height: 500px; max-height: 150px; max-width: 300px; top: 50px; left: 200px"></div>



<script>
  

</script>
```

Comment: I included it I didn't put the whole HTML file

Comment: please try my answer as it is showing alert and fadein at same time @droplet gamb

Answer (score 0):

I have this in an HTML doc in Visual Studio:

```js
$('.border1').click(function(e) {
  $('.image, .border1, .border2, .border3, .border4').fadeOut('slow', function() {
    $('.image, .border2').fadeIn('slow');
  });
});

function clickimageone() {
  alert("test");
  question1button1 = true;
}
```

```css
.border1 {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.border2 {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.border3 {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.border4 {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.image {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="image"><img src="img/500.png" onclick="clickimageone()" class="border1" style="height: 500px; max-height: 150px; max-width: 300px; top: 50px; left: 50px"></div>
<div class="image"><img src="img/1000.png" onclick="clickimagetwo(this)" class="border2" style="height: 500px; max-height: 150px; max-width: 300px; top: 50px; left: 100px"></div>
<div class="image"><img src="img/1500.png" onclick="clickimagethree(this)" class="border3" style="height: 500px; max-height: 150px; max-width: 300px; top: 50px; left: 150px"></div>
<div class="image"><img src="img/2000.png" onclick="clickimagefour(this)" class="border4" style="height: 500px; max-height: 150px; max-width: 300px; top: 50px; left: 200px"></div>
```

When I click the first div, it fades out, alerts, and one div fades back in. Your code is pretty much working.

Comment: I've tested it out locally and the jquery works but the JavaScript does not fire up anything

Comment: Is caching disabled in your browser?

Answer (score 0):

You can chain the `fadeout` and `fadein` events and check for `fadeInComplete` event of the second image like this.

```
$('.border1').click(function (e) {
    $('.border1').fadeOut('slow', function () {
        $('.border2').fadeIn('slow', function () {
            $(this).trigger("fadeInComplete");
        });
    });

    $(".border2").on("fadeInComplete", function () {
        alert("test");
        question1button1 = true;
    });
});
```

```js
$(function () {
 $('.border1').click(function (e) {
  $('.border1').fadeOut('slow', function () {
   $('.border2').fadeIn('slow', function () {
    $(this).trigger("fadeInComplete");
   });
  });

  $(".border2").on("fadeInComplete", function () {
   alert("test");
   question1button1 = true;
  });
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="image"><img src="chicago.jpg" class="border1" style="height: 500px; max-height: 150px; max-width: 300px; top: 50px; left: 50px"></div>
<div class="image"><img src="ny.jpg" class="border2" style="height: 500px; max-height: 150px; max-width: 300px; top: 50px; left: 100px"></div>
<div class="image"><img src="img/1500.png" class="border3" style="height: 500px; max-height: 150px; max-width: 300px; top: 50px; left: 150px"></div>
<div class="image"><img src="img/2000.png" class="border4" style="height: 500px; max-height: 150px; max-width: 300px; top: 50px; left: 200px"></div>
```