# Run two jQuery functions at the same time Parallel

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

god day, I want to ask a question about the jQuery where it is possible to execute more than one event at the same time without waiting for the other process

***as example :***

```
<input type="button" id="btnSave" />
<script>

    $('#btnSave').click(function () {
        //... Do something
    });
    $('#btnSave').click(function () {
        //... Do something else
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Can you describe what's inside those handlers that would make a difference? Give a concrete example of the effect you'd like, perhaps?

Comment: Event should be one, but runned functions two - simple. What is the problem to write few lines more in event initializer body?

Comment: if they should run in parallel that would imply they do not care about each-other, and that would imply paralleling them is irrelevant

Comment: i need do like Thread

Comment: @CertainPerformance , i have idea to new library but i'm asked that is possibility to do this like Threads , and like jquery ajax a sync when true

Comment: @Zydnar , i'm need to run two functions together i the same time not step by step

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9516900/how-can-i-create-an-asynchronous-function-in-javascript

Comment: *As you may probably know, Javascript is single-threaded. To clarify better, this means that one single thread handles the event loop.* - https://medium.com/techtrument/multithreading-javascript-46156179cf9a

Comment: @DinaDiagovic async functions, promises, sounds familiar? If not, just search for it.

Comment: @Twisty there are web workers for more threads and async functions.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you need this:

```
$('#btnSave').click(function () {
        function1();
        function2();
    });
```

Comment: `function1` and `function2` will still run in serial, and not at the same time

Comment: sure it will be in serial, then there's no way to run simultaneously two or more functions as Javascript is single threaded.

Comment: It's possible if some of what the functions do is asynchronous. I think the problem is that OP's question is very unclear.

Comment: Do you mean promises? and then promise.all()?

Comment: i don't need to this way, and it's not working to gether